# How to find broken images for an entire web site in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: image, selenium, web-scraping

I want to find the broken images for the entire site. I can able to do that for only a single page, ex: Home page.

How can we do that for the entire site?

Comment: Does it need to be Selenium? I'd have thought a web crawler would be better for this.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in selenium.

Comment: [Some ideas here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=selenium+site+crawler) - any good?

Answer (score 6):

To check if an image is broken, you can simply check if the `naturalWidth` of the element is 0. You would loop through the images on the page and do this check for each. As for doing this across an entire site, you would have to build a crawler or ideally find an existing one and that's out of scope for a question on SO.

Demo code

```
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/broken_images");
for (WebElement image : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img")))
{
    isImageBroken(image);
}
```

The function to test for broken images

```
public void isImageBroken(WebElement image)
{
    if (image.getAttribute("naturalWidth").equals("0"))
    {
        System.out.println(image.getAttribute("outerHTML") + " is broken.");
    }
}
```

When run, this outputs

```
<img src="asdf.jpg"> is broken.
<img src="hjkl.jpg"> is broken.
```

**Note:** The function above is kinda contrived for this question. It would be better if it returned a `boolean` and validations were done in the test script, e.g.

```
public boolean imageExists(WebElement image)
{
    return !image.getAttribute("naturalWidth").equals("0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've following code for you; but this has following dependencies/limitations:

1) It runs on chrome (can me modified to work with other browsers)

2) Browser should be open when running this code (because it makes use of Java Robot class) so after hitting RUN, let the browser be open:

3) Thread.sleep(5000) is intended do-not change that.

```
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List <WebElement>  allImages = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));

        for(WebElement img :allImages){

            String imgSrc = img.getAttribute("src");

            String baseHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.contextClick(img).build().perform();

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            Robot robot = new Robot();

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

            allHandles.remove(baseHandle);

            String newHandle = null;
            for(String str : allHandles){

                newHandle = str;
            }

            driver.switchTo().window(newHandle);    

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if(driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("not found")){

                System.out.println(imgSrc  + "Image is broken!");


            }

            driver.close();

            driver.switchTo().window(baseHandle);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);




        }
```

Comment: Most of this code has nothing to do with the question and this is not a good way to detect broken images. It's going to take forever to navigate to every image on the page.

Comment: yup.. your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will help you.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
            int brokenImagesCount=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(links.get(i));
                String linkURL=links.get(i).getAttribute("src");
                System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
                URL url = new URL(linkURL);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                http.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
                http.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                http.setReadTimeout(20000);
                int statusCode=http.getResponseCode();
                if(statusCode==404||statusCode==500){
                    brokenImagesCount=brokenImagesCount+1;
                    System.out.println(linkURL+"and its Status codes is:"+statusCode);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("total number of broken images are: "+brokenImagesCount);
```

Please update me if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get xpath and then using tag name; get all the links in the page
2. Click on each and every link in the page
3. In the target page title, look for 404/500 error.

   ```
    public static void verifyimgActive(WebElement img)
      { 
        try
      { 
        HttpResponse response = new 
        DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(img.getAttribute(“src”))); 
       if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) 
      {  
          invalidimg++;  
       } 
     catch (Exception e)
       {
        e.printStackTrace();
         } 
        } }
   ```